# OpenCV - ArUco : detectMarkers failed identified some markers in a photos

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, aruco

I have pictures containing ArUco markers but I am unable to detect all of them with the detectMarkers function. Actually, I have many pictures : in some of them I can detect all the markers, in others I cannot and I don't really understand why.

I thought it was because of the quality of the photo, but it seems to be not so simple. Here's an example of my code :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cv2 import aruco

aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_1000)
inputfile = 'EOS-1D-X-Mark-II_1201-ConvertImage.jpg'
frame = cv2.imread(inputfile)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
parameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(frame, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
frame_markers = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame.copy(),rejectedImgPoints)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(frame_markers)
for i in range(len(ids)):
    c = corners[i][0]
    plt.plot([c[:, 0].mean()], [c[:, 1].mean()], "o", label = "id={0}".format(ids[i]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HPsU.jpg), 1 marker is not detected and I don't understand why.

I tried to tune the parameters of detectMarkers function manually with an interactive method thanks to jupyter notebook. There are many parameters and I found nothing that really helped me, except in some photos the reduction of polygonalApproxAccuracyRate.

The photo is orginally in 5472 x 3648 pixels but the one I send in this post is 2189 x 1459 pixels. Note that it doesn't work with the better resolution neither. Actually, I found in some photos that reducing the resolution help to detect the markers ... It's a contradiction but I think this is because the default parameters of the function are not adapted to my pictures, but I found no solution when tuning the parameters.

Another idea is to use the refineDetectMarkers function after calling detectMarkers. It uses the candidates that were found in detectMarkers but failed to be identified, and try to refine their identification. However, as far as I understood, I need to know where my markers should be in the picture and put it in refineDetectMarkers (as a board). In my situation, I don't know where the markers should be, otherwise I wouldn't take photos. The photos are used to observe precisely the evolution of their positions.

I am interested in any ideas you may have, thanks for reading !

Comment: which marker is it? the weird one that isn't drawn correctly?

Comment: The marker at the bottom-right of the picture. Its id should be 306.

Comment: yeah the bottom edge of that one looks too narrow.  it's not a "pixel" size. it must also be square. looks more rectangular. take a permanent marker, add some black; use a ruler. I don't know how robust aruco is. potentially the bright/blown out beam in the background could disturb thresholding, if that's how it works. it might not.

Comment: Hum so you think that whatever the choices of the parameters is, this marker won't be identified because of its shape ? It's true that especially this marker is never identified, whatever the angle of the photo.

Comment: If that may help, I found what was the problem : the aruco markers are surronded by black lines, that's what disturb the detection. ArUco markers must have large white spaces arround them.